# How to install openCV on python3 file rather than python2.7?

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04

I find there is only python2.7 folder in `~/.local/lib` (see below). When I use openCV, I must use `python **.py`. But I want to us `python3 **.py` to us openCV.

How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: every Python needs own module - you should have `pip3` or even `pip3.6` or `pip3.7` to install module for selected version. Eventually `python3 -m pip install ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

to install opencv to your python3 site-packages

https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

this will allow your python3 scripts to use the opencv pkg

if you don't want to use pip, seems there is more info here:

[similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783956/how-to-install-opencv-3-1-for-python-3-5-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts)